# Select a value from a cell based on a range

Tags: excel

I am trying to solve a problem. I don't even know if this question's heading is correct or if I am using the right terminology. So please feel free to correct me.

I have two sheets coming from two different systems. One provides me with a department name and one doesn't. I need to add the department name from my first sheet to my second sheet. The common value between these two lists is email addresses.

Please look at the image below.

- In Column E5 I want to bring the value from Column K8 because the value in B5 is found in Column J at J8.
- If the value doesn't match, in that case, we'll leave the cell empty.
- Based on these rules, I want to fill the data in Column E

[image: Sample Data]

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: You can do that with VLOOKUP()

Comment: VLOOKUP worked like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While `VLookup()` works fine you can also use `Index()` and `Match()` functions like below.

```
=INDEX($K$5:$K$14,MATCH(B5,$J$5:$J$14,0))
```